# How to match the type of an object's value given its associated key in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I need to delete an item from an array in cache. Items can be of different types. When deleting from the cache we hint to TypeScript what type of item we're deleting, `ItemA` or `ItemB`. I can't figure out how to ensure that the value matches the type of the associated key provided.

Here is the delete operation:

```js
type ItemA = { id: number; name: string; isPrivate: boolean };

// Should error because `id` should be a number but we're passing it a string
cacheDel<ItemA>(cacheStore, "arrayOfItemA", "id", "not-a-number");
```

Here is the full toy project:

```js
type CacheStore = Record<string, unknown[]>;

const cacheGet = <T>(store: CacheStore, hash: keyof CacheStore) => {
  return store[hash] as T[];
};

const cachePut = <T>(store: CacheStore, hash: keyof CacheStore, array: T[]) => {
  return (store[hash] = array);
};

const cacheDel = <T>(store: CacheStore, hash: keyof CacheStore, key: keyof T, value: T[keyof T]) => {
  const data = cacheGet<T>(store, hash);
  const updatedData = [...data.filter((item) => item[key] !== value)];
  cachePut(store, hash, updatedData);
};

type ItemA = { id: number; name: string; isPrivate: boolean };
type ItemB = { token: string; label: string; counter: number };

const cacheStore = {
  arrayOfItemA: [
    { id: 1, name: "item A", isPrivate: true },
    { id: 2, name: "item AA", isPrivate: false },
  ],
  arrayOfItemB: [
    { token: "aaaaa", label: "hello" },
    { token: "bbbbb", label: "bye" },
  ],
};
cacheDel<ItemA>(cacheStore, "arrayOfItemA", "id", "not-a-number"); // Should error because not a number
cacheDel<ItemB>(cacheStore, "arrayOfItemB", "token", 1); // Should error because not a string
```

How can I make sure that the last two statements fail until the right value type is passed depending on the key provided?

Comment: You can't do this without redefining how `cacheDel()` is called.  You'd need another generic type parameter `K` for the compiler to keep track of the particular value passed in for `key`, but TypeScript doesn't support *partial type argument inference* (as requested in [ms/TS#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242)) so there are only workarounds.  A common one is *currying*, where instead of `<T, K extends keyof T>(k: K) => void` you write `<T,>() => <K extends keyof T>(k: K) => void`.  Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NdY1dm).

Comment: If that fully addresses your question I can write it up as an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz, thanks for your comment. It's a bummer that the code must be changed. Sure, you can write up an answer, seems like a valid approach. You suggested that _currying_ is one of the workarounds. Are you familiar with any other one?

Comment: If you make the cache store generic, you won't need partial inference as all arguments can be inferred. Something like this might work: https://tsplay.dev/N9Px1w It will also check whether the key argument matches the hash.

Comment: Another workaround is to introduce a dummy parameter of type `T`, even if you don't actually have a value of that type, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mM1g1m).  But... if your real code is like this example, then as Oblosys says, you don't need to "hint" anything; the compiler can infer it all like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WP9kzw).  Is *that* what you want to see instead?  Or do you really have a store that's "opaque" to the compiler where you need hints?  Let me know how to proceed (and mention me via @jcalz or I won't be notified)

Comment: @jcalz: Isn't your second version just a less abstract and slightly less type-safe version of my solution? Or is there a reason why you'd want to avoid the `filter` helper?

Comment: Anyway, I forgot the type signature on `cacheStore` in the first version. https://tsplay.dev/Nlenlm

Comment: Thanks @jcalz, as you said my cache is opaque to the compiler and I need to give it hints. In my real-life code the `delete()` function takes the cache "client" (to get/set cache data) and the key/value pair to find the item with a matching key/value to remove it. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Oblosys I implemented my own version without really looking at yours.  I wasn't trying to imply mine was an improvement in any way over yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you said the cache is opaque to the compiler and it cannot know which array element types correspond with which keys, then for this example I'm just going to [`declare`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html#global-variables) the `cacheStore` variable to be of type `CacheStore` so that I'm not tempted to give you more type inference than you can use:

```
type CacheStore = Record<string, unknown[]>;
declare const cacheStore: CacheStore;
```

---

If you want the compiler to keep track of the [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the value passed in as `cacheDel()`'s `key` parameter, then you need to make `cacheDel()` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in that type.  This means your function needs to be generic in two type parameters; the type `T` of the cached value in the array, and the type `K extends keyof T` of `key`.

Unfortunately we immediately run into a current limitation of TypeScript as of TS4.8.  You are manually *specifying* the `T` type argument, but you would want the compiler to *infer* the `K` type argument.  And TypeScript doesn't support *partial type argument inference* as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242).  When you call a generic function with multiple type parameters, you either need to let the compiler infer *all* of them, or you manually specify some parameters in which case the compiler will *not infer any* of them.  (No, [generic parameter defaults](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) do not give you inference.)  So while it would be great if we could write something like this:

```
// ☠          DO NOT USE          ☠ // 
// ☠ THIS IS NOT VALID TYPESCRIPT ☠ //
const cacheDel = <T, K extends keyof T = infer>(
    store: CacheStore, // nope ------> ^^^^^^^
    hash: keyof CacheStore,
    key: K,
    value: T[K]
) => { };
```

There's just no direct support for it.

There *are* workarounds, but they all involve changing how you call `cacheDel()`, at least a little.

---

The most common one is [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), where you split a single multi-parameter generic function like `<T, K>(k: K)=>void` into a generic single-parameter function which returns another single-parameter generic function like `<T,>() => <K,>(k: K) => void`.  Then you can manually specify the first generic type argument, and then you let the compiler infer the other one in the returned function.  Here's how it looks for `cacheDel()`:

```
const cacheDel = <T,>() => <K extends keyof T>(
    // currying --> ^^^^^^^^
    store: CacheStore,
    hash: keyof CacheStore,
    key: K,
    value: T[K]
) => {
    const data = cacheGet<T>(store, hash);
    const updatedData = [...data.filter((item) => item[key] !== value)];
    cachePut(store, hash, updatedData);
};

cacheDel<ItemA>()(cacheStore, "someA", "id", "not-a-number"); // error    
cacheDel<ItemA>()(cacheStore, "someA", "id", 1); // okay
cacheDel<ItemB>()(cacheStore, "someB", "token", 1); // error
cacheDel<ItemB>()(cacheStore, "someB", "token", "okay"); // okay
```

So you have to change how you call `cacheDel` by adding in an extra set of parentheses, but it has the effect you want.

---

Another workaround is to give the function a *dummy* parameter of the type you would normally specify, and then let inference work on the whole thing. So instead of `<T, K>(k: K)=>void` you have `<T, K>(k: K, dummyT: T)=>void` (you could put the dummy parameter first if you prefer; the position isn't important) This parameter is not needed by the function implementation, so you don't even have to pass in a real value of that type; you can pass in something random you can [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to be of your type.  I usually use `null!` which is of type `never` but you can do whatever.  Here's how it could look for `cacheDel()`:

```
const cacheDel = <T, K extends keyof T>(
    store: CacheStore,
    hash: keyof CacheStore,
    key: K,
    value: T[K],
    dummyT: T // <-- dummying
) => {
    const data = cacheGet<T>(store, hash);
    const updatedData = [...data.filter((item) => item[key] !== value)];
    cachePut(store, hash, updatedData);
};

const _ = null!;
cacheDel(cacheStore, "someA", "id", "not-a-number", _ as ItemA); // error
cacheDel(cacheStore, "someA", "id", 1, _ as ItemA); // okay
cacheDel(cacheStore, "someB", "token", 1, _ as ItemB); // error
cacheDel(cacheStore, "someB", "token", "okay", _ as ItemB); // okay
```

So you have to change how you call `cacheDel` by putting `,_ as ItemA` instead of `<ItemA>`, but it has the effect you want.

---

If you really don't want to change the runtime implementation of `cacheDel`, you could try a combination of the above approaches, by using [branding](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal) on one of the existing parameters.  So instead of `<T, K>(k: K) => void`, you have `<T, K>(k: Branded<K, T>) => void` where `Branded<K, T>` is actually of type `K`, but you've "branded" it with some type information about `T`, like `type Branded<K> = K & {__brand: T}`.

Instead of going into explaining that in the abstract, I'll show the example for `cacheDel`:

```
type HashFor<T> = keyof CacheStore & { __dataItemType: T };
const hashFor = <T,>(k: keyof CacheStore) => k as HashFor<T>;

const cacheDel = <T, K extends keyof T>(
    store: CacheStore,
    hash: HashFor<T>,
    key: K,
    value: T[K],
) => {
    const data = cacheGet<T>(store, hash);
    const updatedData = [...data.filter((item) => item[key] !== value)];
    cachePut(store, hash, updatedData);
};

cacheDel(cacheStore, hashFor<ItemA>("someA"), "id", "not-a-number"); // error
cacheDel(cacheStore, hashFor<ItemA>("someA"), "id", 1); // okay
cacheDel(cacheStore, hashFor<ItemB>("someB"), "token", 1); // error
cacheDel(cacheStore, hashFor<ItemB>("someB"), "token", "okay"); // okay
```

Conceptually, the value you pass in for the `hash` parameter should determine the type of the data being stored, but the compiler doesn't know about it.  The developer can help the compiler by telling it that, say, `"someA"` points to an array of `ItemA` elements.  We do so by passing in `hashFor<ItemA>("someA")`.  If you look at the implementation of `hashFor()`, you'll see that it just returns its argument, so at runtime it's just `"someA"` and the implementation of `cacheDel()` doesn't have to change.  But at compiler is being tricked into believing that the returned value has a `__dataItemType` property of type `ItemA`, which means that now the compiler can infer `ItemA` when you call `cacheDel`.

As mentioned, it's a combination of the currying and dummying approaches; you need an extra function call where you manually specify the type argument, `hashFor<T>()` versus `cacheDel<T>()`, and you need to pretend to pass in a value of the type `T` in order for the compiler to infer things, pretending `"someA"` is of type `"someA" & {__itemDataType: T}` vs pretending `null` is of type `T`.

---

Anyway, hopefully one of the three workarounds presented will suffice for your use case... until and unless partial type argument inference is implemented.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghgYwBYQMrAPYCdoF4oBKEC2AJgDwDOwWAlgHYDmANFAK70DW9GA7vQG0AugD4A3AFgAUKWIAbODigl61ZYhTpsEAFywNaTDklTpKtQgMBxCMCj5yAFWYiAFNW174yQ9tZI4SiQ9TggQDAAzfR8tHABKexEoAG9pKHSoHGA2LHooDxwBAKChKECoR2ETAF8TMwxVO0sfAAU2OwdnNwLdaM0jCH9A4KhQ8Kjvfr8yrCw4ED1KoQTcJNSpDMzbHLz3AaLh0vxFOZA4mrqpUEgoAElgCABbAEF7FKhaUj16NkeAIwgWDEUHocEevWodCYwNolBadAAbnAHno-hgMHIIHA8rVpNdoPcngAhN7JKCYUL0PSQhiMYEKAFyak0WnAkgcB5Yb6-AFYKC40yC0HgyhgRDQAByGBu602AHoAFQVJCwqCkDAQSj0ADkdl42E4aQy5iaBgAIhA5G8nKwANJQCAADwe9FIlFGYUiFTeDAigLcRs26R6XgMsUGgaDxRGYy9k18OGYkc2Yz0tqTGyD6SRcjYvUqtqEkZWa2TxoaalIyLgb2aKBswCc3QGQyC5zL6RN7DAVYepDN1beAgAdKPe3BhxFaHJOa5XLQHo8Sx9FwIxqUAIS4fA5vNxIQmLOdgxtYB7abR1hsHvIiD96vtzPpAWRusQC1yciEl5uN-h1gAESUBg4LPABgGfOBUAATwwAALRwHBPz-ICAHnFAcpyg6szYJsr7mpaX6Ls8v5hi20HAaBUEAZBrAAIzoZhUAYJw8z4T4H5EcSpExORQEgRARLURSED0FBDHAkxgJYNg7EoJx35EjxUyJhRAlCYBIliYBLHzGhklYbpICRgqcrSNU0jSMKmpigg0AwDkWAgCkllPsoFamhxlrWl0rjLuQ9pOi6boeuMFQBm58pYQgjkgLSUBwXBSQAHqpWlqUdvkAyhrxfiZdGISehMZF5ZFGSplA6aZbu+YCIWxaJC5ZWdh5aqDvgb4Nk256qdGj5Hu5jTdr2d4DsANb4COY7VpO06zvOi7LguTxrmEm7blANX7oeR5vqePWDFAl7Dbe97jf1GQvm5b4KcRbhxK4f58ZREBgRBpDUbBCFITyqGMVh0m4RkcnvoR34kX5j0lap-FUe94n-cxrHGddBGfop91Q7lMMvRp0FaQjBnYTJWAg7d3GQ090yw4JwksaJ1FGfpGGGcjrkWUKYI2eKUBmr8jzOesr6tTd3mdHaDrOqJIWxlEjgRQNIZ9AmEbNUdwyFWF8b-plFVVWrNWLHVQgZgNpD8yAjiLCzUDkIlaoW7SDWrE1A1duOtbWLY3U9K2SAXVmXbXiNZ0TVAU3DuOs0zoCc7LUujXx6tIDrTucC5hA22ZXt7QHX7V43n2Y1wAH-KXJsXYAPpvD8chyBuO3Hl5chYyph00290G0dBX2IchvJQdX5Tg4jgOk6jzetyrgEvZ3NEffRrBD+6I9E0ZZOWlP-5qeCeMAQTi9QMvdyLkSo84ePFdo1vz3qXTlKM8jg9lCvp+I+vUgc1ZXOijztphAACQYJyJqkZ8RQAAcMAAYtgJsbxZbK3DFAAAZO8SuldxzfkcOAfMZdhZDWjDAvk4s3CcE1nGaGmdGqcBfhA6BsD5bl3LENUWVpxaVUlsFd0CD5auEykrbWLZ8oazoUEIhTZTZHj1pIrMhsKjGxkVAZcspdqtQ9h1L2jZeG+3Vm2RuQYg6F1Gu1cOo5I4zSnDHLAcdFqJ1XOuKAW404ZyzmrHOZ4dHHWDqdYupcrpX0nlTXq9CsBcR-K4DuaF4aAV7j9FCWBmZSQvhvFuQTDqENgeDNwkS4jRKgBJG2H8AnyU3mkv24iMYRNxlE-G9NtL5PPiTFJN8LwhLCUpKpd9cm1IfjpJ+782aCmqEAA)

Comment: This is an excellent answer, thank you so much @jcalz! What you say makes sense. I'm going to evaluate each approach in my real-life code and see what suits me better. The currying approach definitely feels less intrusive at a first glance.